# React Native Android - Promise.all throws [TypeError: [object Object] is not iterable!] for an array of promises

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-native, expo

I'm using react native and expo.
I have this code:

```
const a = {};
const promises = [];
someArray.forEach(c => {
    a[c] = {
        ref: firebase.ref(`someref/${c}`),
        data: null
    }
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       a[c].ref.on('value', (snap) => {
            const data = snap.val() || {};
            // do something with data
            resolve(data);
        },
        (err) => {
            console.error(err)
            return reject(err)
        })
    }))
});

function isIterable(obj) {
    // checks for null and undefined
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === 'function';
}

console.log(promises)
console.log(isIterable(promises))

Promise.all(promises).then((values)=>{
    console.log("promise all values", values)
}).catch(e=>{
    console.error("promise all failed",e)
})
```

I'm getting this error `promise all failed TypeError: [object Object] is not iterable!` when running on Android.
**It's working fine on iOS and on remote debug JS mode**.
The `console.log(promises)` result is

```
Array [
   Promise {
     "_a": undefined,
     "_c": Array [],
     "_d": false,
     "_h": 0,
     "_n": false,
    "_s": 0,
    "_v": undefined,
   },
 ]
```

and the strange thing is the `console.log(isIterable(promises))` prints `false`

any ideas?

Comment: What is your output of `console.log(promises.length)` and `console.log(promises)` just before `Promis.all()` ?

Comment: It's an array of promisses [ Promise, Promise]

Comment: This is really weird. What does `isIterable([])` print?

Comment: You should use `map`, not `forEach` + `push`

Comment: `isIterable([])` prints false

Comment: Uh, that environment doesn't look ES6-compatible… or was severely broken by some other code. What does `console.log(Symbol, Symbol.iterator, [][Symbol.iterator])` print?

Comment: it gives me an error - Can't find variable Symbol - looked into it and found this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15902 
the solution is inside

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, react native on android doesn't support es6 symbols.
Found the solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15902#issuecomment-373964965)

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  if (typeof Symbol === 'undefined') {
    console.log('Polyfilling Symbol on Android');
    require('es6-symbol/implement');
    console.log('Polyfilling Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator] on Android');
    if (Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator] === undefined) {
      Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
        let i = 0;
        return {
          next: () => ({
            done: i >= this.length,
            value: this[i++],
          }),
        };
      };
    }
  }
}
```